# C# Timer With Lambda Instead of Method Reference?

Tags: c#, timer, lambda

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var secondsElapsed = 0;

Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( iterateSecondsElapsed);
myTimer.Interval = 1000;
myTimer.Start();


//Somewhere else in the code:
public static void iterateSecondsElapsed( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
{
    secondsElapsed++; 
}
```

Is there any way to do this WITHOUT defining the DisplayTimEvent static method? Something like:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( secondsElapsed => secondsElapsed ++);
```

I realize I am showing a profound lack of understanding of lambdas here, but nonetheless...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, just:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => secondsElapsed++;
```

The parameters for the lambda expression have to match the parameters for the delegate that you're trying to convert it to, basically.

Depending on whether the `Timer` you're using always fires on the same thread or not, you may want to use:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => Interlocked.Increment(ref secondsElapsed);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

```
myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {secondsElapsed++;};
```

Comment: Thanks, will come back to accept  since you were first.

Comment: Thanks ^_^, I knew this one would be a tight race.

Comment: I am really surprised no one asked this question before (at least from what I found).

Comment: @VSO: Not first according to the timestamps I can see... (14:42:14Z vs 14:41:53Z)... but you can accept whichever one you want to. It's always an OP's prerogative to use whatever criteria they want for accepting an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought he was first from the way it showed up on my screen. I never figured out how to view exact times, just ("answered 5 mins ago"). Will figure it out now and accept whichever was first. Maybe my subconscious was just rooting for the underdog here =)

Comment: haha sorry Rariolu, apparently hovering over the time gives an exact time stamp. Can't beat the Skeet. I did upvote your answer and appreciate it.

Comment: @VSO: Again: there's nothing to say you have to accept the first answer. If you want to accept Rariolu's answer, go ahead :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Nope, you were first and gave more detail. I just enjoy watching people beat you to the punch on C# questions since it never happens =) Very close though Rariolu!